# this.setState is failing to pass information from res.data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run my code like this, the console shows an empty array. However when I use console.log(res.data) I get the expected json object of employees without a problem.

```js
  state = {
    userList: [],
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    position: ""
  };

loadUsers = () => {
  API.getUsers()
    .then(res =>
      this.setState({ userList: res.data, firstName: "", lastName: "", 
      position: "" })
    )
    .then (console.log(this.state.userList))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Either way the code is run I also get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () error message.

Comment: is res.data a string or an object - do console.log(typeof res.data)

Comment: `.then (console.log(this.state.userList))` should be `.then (() => console.log(this.state.userList))`. However, note that `setState` doesn't update the state immediately. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     .then (console.log(this.state.userList))
```

That immeadiately calls console.log, logs the current state (way before the async stuff even starts), console.log returns undefined and the whole thing evaluates to

```
 .then(undefined)
```

Instead, pass a function to `.then`, e.g.

```
.then(() => {
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

However as setState is also asynchronous, that won't work reliably. Therefore you should use the callback that one can pass to setState, so that you log after the async action was done and the state was updated:

```
this.setState(
  { userList: res.data, firstName: "", lastName: "", position: "" },
  () => console.log("done", this.state)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asychronous so you are not guaranteed to have the state value updated by the time you are checking it with `console.log`

`async/await` to the rescue

```
state = {
  userList: [],
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  position: ""
};

loadUsers = async () => {
  const response = await API.getUsers();
  this.setState({
    ...state,
    userList: response.data, 
  }, () => console.log('[user list]', this.state.userList)
};
```

**Update**

Added the spread syntax

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)